# Vue-cli-service: watch for file changes/recompile when edit

Tags: vue.js, frontend, development-environment, vue-cli, hot-reload

I'm currently building a Vue.js app using **vue/cli-service@4.5.17**.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I change a .vue file, the server does not recompile, restart, or do anything.

I use this command (through `package.json`) to run the server in development environment:

```
NODE_ENV=development vue-cli-service serve
```

My `vue.config.js` file is:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    hot: true
  },
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

This is the output, and it does not change if I edit a file while the server is running:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 17169ms                                                                                                                                      12:01:45 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://localhost:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

EDIT: I would like to add that a friend who is working on the same project and who start the server the same way as I do has the expected watch/reload feature. Is there a hidden environment variable to set or something?

I also would like to add that I'm using WSL2 to start the development server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried adding the  --watch flag to the build command. Doesent look like it is in watch mode

Comment: @NobleEugene I'm not using the build command, I'm using the serve command. A friend who launch the project the exact same way (with serve) does have the expected watch/reload feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found something.

This is an issue with WSL2 not being able to trigger file change notifications: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739 .

I tried using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and with adding:

```
server: {
  watch: {
    usePolling: true
  }
}
```

To the `vite.config.js`, it does work properly with WSL2 [as explained here](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-watch).